# Raspberry Pi SMBv2

Tags: pi-2, samba, share

I'm trying to setup an SMB folder share from a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B that I can access from Windows 10. When trying to connect from Windows, I'm getting the below.

[image: SMB1 Protocol Disabled]

Obviously I could just enable SMB1 from Windows features but.....no thanks.

I've added "min protocol=SMB2" to the config, in both global and that specific share but this has had no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have fixed the above by changing "min protocol=SMB2" to "protocol=SMB2". However, I'm now being told that Windows can't find the path. It tells me that it can find the pi, but not /mnt, which is the next step in the share path. Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps `/mnt` does not have the necessary permissions for sharing

Comment: ls -l shows /mnt as having 777?

Comment: do you have the share name set up correctly? ... https://www.htpcguides.com/create-samba-share-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Show u smb.conf in your question, else it's a guessing game.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, it was an issue with the share path and the name of the share in smb.conf. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)